# Tool to Interpolate Map Tile Levels

Tags: tiles

I'm using a tile service that has different imagery sources at different zoom levels e.g. when zoomed out clouds and older imagery are shown, but as you zoom in to higher resolution imagery the clouds are lost and imagery is more recent.

Ideally I'd like to provide a tile service where the imagery is consistent through all zoom levels. Are there any tools I could use to generate or proxy a tile collection based on specific zoom levels from the original tile source, interpolating the other zoom levels from the desired levels?

I've had a good look around MapProxy as a potential solution, but I couldn't see any useful options there for this usage case.

If I can't find anything I intend to code a solution up to generate the tiles, but I imagine this is a problem that has already been solved somewhere by one or more tools that I've not encountered yet.

Comment: This could help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123395/creating-my-own-slippy-map-from-geotiff-images

Comment: @TimothyDalton thanks for that, but I guess you mean stitch the tiles from highest zoom level together then use GeoServer to serve tiles based on that. Unfortunately the area will be a bit too large so I'd imagine I'd encounter issues with that approach.